# How to add class to parent, if only first and last child having specific class

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

can somebody please help on my jQuery issue.

I have Bootstrap slider in my code.

Every time I click on Next/Prev arrow, respective div is getting class “selected”.

Now I want to add class to parent when only first and last divs having class “selected”

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">                                      
    <div id="carousel-selector-0" class="thumb selected" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></div>                                             
    <div id="carousel-selector-1" class="thumb " data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></div>
    <div id="carousel-selector-2" class="thumb " data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></div>
    <div id="carousel-selector-3" class="thumb " data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></div>
    <div id="carousel-selector-4" class="thumb " data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
   
</div>
```

---

```
if ($(".thumb").first().hasClass("selected")) {
     $(".carousel").addClass("new-class");
   } else {
     $(".carousel").removeClass("new-class");
}

if ($(".thumb").last().hasClass("selected")) {
     $(".carousel").addClass("new-class");
   } else {
     $(".carousel").removeClass("new-class");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

just attach these to the buttons, as in

```
$('[data-slide="prev"], [data-slide="back"]').click(function() {
      if ($(".thumb").first().hasClass("selected")) {
        $(".carousel").addClass("new-class");
      } else {
        $(".carousel").removeClass("new-class");
      }

      if ($(".thumb").last().hasClass("selected")) {
        $(".carousel").addClass("new-class");
      } else {
        $(".carousel").removeClass("new-class");
      }
    }
```